# Traveling Salesman where the cost depend on visiting a city before some other city.

Tags: optimization

I'm looking for some inspiration about how to approach this problem. I'm currently assuming this is some variation of the traveling salesman problem, but there might be better fitting optimization problems.

I have a set of cities and a traveling salesman that must visit all cities, starting in any city and ending in any other city. In general, any move from a city to another city is free, `cost = 0`. However, there is a set of moves that are penalized: e.g. if city `2 is visited before 4` or if `5 is visited before 1`.

For example, for cities`{1,2,3,4,5}`and the tour `3-5-1-4-2`and the penalizing set, i `{(5,2), (1,3), (3,4)} results in costs of` 2`, due to the 1st and 3rd rule.

Please note, that rules can also contradict each other: `{(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)}` or `{(1,2), (2,1)}`is a feasible set too.

I wrote a brute force and a 2-opt solver. Using the brute force solver (on all permutation) is only feasible for small problems, until about 8 cities. The 2-opt solver often fails to provide good results for 12 cities or more. A greedy solver would probably result in terrible tours, as the evaluation of the cost function only makes sense on the overall tour, and not a single fragment.

Of course, I could do SA or some other form of more general heuristics, but I first would be interested in learning more about the problem per se. Are there better analog problems instead of the traveling salesman? It seems to more of an ordering problem (*if this is a thing*, I don't know).